# Scala classOf for type parameter

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a generic method for object updates using scala / java but I can't get the class for a type parameter.

Here is my code:

```
object WorkUnitController extends Controller {     
 def updateObject[T](toUpdate: T, body: JsonObject){
  val source = gson.fromJson(body, classOf[T]);
  ...
 }
}
```

The error i get is

> class type required but T found

I know in java you can't do it but is this possible in scala at all?

Thanks!

Comment: See also: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5722

Comment: You can simply do it in Java in this way: 
```public <T> void updateObject(T toUpdate, JsonObject body) {
 gson.fromJson(body, toUpdate.getClass());
}```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Due **Manifest** is **deprecated** (Since Scala 2.10.0) this is the updated answer -

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect._

object WorkUnitController extends Controller {
  def updateObject[T: ClassTag](toUpdate: T, body: JsonObject){
    val source = gson.fromJson(body, classTag[T].runtimeClass)
    ???
  }
}
```

You should use `ClassTag` instead of `ClassManifest`
and `.runtimeClass` instead of `.erasure`

**Original answer -**
Yes, you can do that using manifests:

```
object WorkUnitController extends Controller {     
 def updateObject[T: ClassManifest](toUpdate: T, body: JsonObject){
  val source = gson.fromJson(body, classManifest[T].erasure);
  ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Oh god that's amazing! I wish I'd known about this earlier!

Comment: I was reading about manifests that "Starting with version 2.7.2, Scala has added manifests, an undocumented (and still experimental) feature"
I'm using scala 2.8 do you know if it is still experimental?

Comment: You can even write `manifest[T]` instead of `implicitly[Manifest[T]]`.

Comment: @mericano1 they've become an essential part of the language, and, I think, Manifests are no longer an experimental feature

Comment: @mericano1 Manifests are still subject to change, but `ClassManifest` is required for handling generic array instantiation, faster than `Manifest`, and support `erasure` just as well.

Comment: Could you update your answer with an example call to updateObject()? I'm struggling to figure out the right types for the call

Comment: You should be able to call it right away, passing just 2 parameters. Manifest will be provided implicitly, w/o any effort from your side.

Comment: @Alex will be smth like this -> `WorkUnitController.updateObject(yourTypedObject, body)`

Comment: @mericano1 One update: `Manifest` and `ClassManifest` are now deprecated, having been replaced with `TypeTag` and `ClassTag`, respectively, on Scala 2.10.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral `TypeTag`s are not production ready. Unfortunately at this moment Scala runtime reflection is completely unstable.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this solution using 2.10.1. Given the comment about deprecation I tried something like this:

def thaw[T:ClassTag]( js:String )(implicit mapper:ObjectMapper) : T = {
    mapper.readValue(js, ClassTag[T]) // orig. needs readValue(js, classOf[T])
}
This give me an error. Any ideas? Thanks, Greg

Comment: @Greg What error? This is not topic for comments -- ask a question.

Comment: @Greg you need to use `classTag[T].runtimeClass` instead of `classOf[T]` when using `ClassTag`s.

Comment: Just updted the answer to classTag

Comment: Instead of `classTag[T].runtimeClass` I needed `classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]`. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Would be interesting to get the answer. Basically what is the difference between Class[_] and Class[T] at run-time or compile time.

Answer (score 10):

Vasil's and Maxim's answer helped me.

Personally, I prefer the syntax where `implicit` is used for adding such parameters (the presented `: ClassTag` is shorthand for it. So here, in case someone else also sees this to be a better way:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object WorkUnitController extends Controller {
  def updateObject[T](toUpdate: T, body: JsonObject)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]){
    val source = gson.fromJson(body, tag.runtimeClass)
    ???
  }
}
```

Demonstration: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Vij5rpHNRDCPPG1WHo566g