# Scala ClassManifest instead of Type[T]

Tags: scala

The following code

```
def httpPost[T: ClassManifest](data: AnyRef): T = {
  val webResource = client.resource("http://localhost..")
  val resp = webResource.post(classOf[ClientResponse], data)
  resp.getEntity(classManifest[T].erasure) //Need classOf[T] here 
}
```

results in this type mismatch compilation error

```
[INFO]  found   : _$1 where type _$1
[INFO]  required: T
[INFO]       resp.getEntity(classManifest[T].erasure)
```

Based on the answer to [Scala classOf for type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200253/scala-classof-for-type-parameter) it looks like it should work.

The erasure method returns java.lang.Class[_] and I presume that this is the problem so I have two questions:

- Why does the class manifest return an existential type and not simply Class[T] - if it's the erasure of T, surely that will always be _ (underscore) because T is obviously unknown, which means its return value isn't as useful as I'd have expected.
- What do I need to do to make the code work!

**Update:**

Thanks Kim and Jean-Phillipe for your answers.

I had previously tried a cast so the original last line was replaced with

```
val responseData = resp.getEntity(classManifest[T].erasure) //Runtime error
responseData.asInstanceOf[T]
```

and this compiles but there's now a runtime error because the getEntity method is passed the class of Object, which it can't process because it needs a more specific type (for which it has a handler). Although it's deferred until runtime, it again comes down to the erasure method not giving specific type information and that's why I thought that to solve the problem, the inline example must be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something seriously wrong with this code. In particular:

```
def httpPost[T: ClassManifest](data: AnyRef): T = {
  val webResource = client.resource("http://localhost..")
  val resp = webResource.post(classOf[ClientResponse], data)
  resp.getEntity(classManifest[T].erasure) //Need classOf[T] here 
}
```

How is Scala supposed to know what the type of `T` is? Are you passing it explicitly when invoking `httpPost`? I suspect not, and that's the reason why `erasure` is returning `Object` for you.

As for why `ClassManifest#erasure` returns `Class[_]` instead of something else, I suspect the reason is that this is the type used by most Java methods, and since `Class` is invariant, if `erasure` returned `Class[T]`, then you'd have to cast it to use it with those methods!

Comment: Thanks for for your comments. There's nothing wrong with the code as per my original update (about the cast). However, I wasn't using a type parameter at the invocation site - I thought that it would be inferred from the assignment target. It worked with that addition.

Answer (score 0):

First question: No idea...

Second question: I think it is safe to cast here. You can use `foo.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that an existential type is returned to make it clear that the cast that you may want to make is your responsibility. `Class` is a bit weird: for instance, a `Class[List[String]]` should actually be typed as a `Class[List[_]]` as it does not carry any information about the `String` parametrization of `List`. The cast suggested by Kim is always safe when `T` is not itself a parametrized type.