# Scala classOf for type parameter: how to call the function and how to restrict with upper type bounds

Tags: scala

I'm working with JAX-RS in Scala and trying to parameterise a call to:

```
val jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(classOf[MyClassName])
```

I've been using ClassManifests as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200253/scala-classof-for-type-parameter) but have a couple of things I'm still struggling with. As background, my JAX-RS representations all extend a stubbed Representation class:

```
class Representation {}

class ExampleRepresentation extends Representation { ... }
```

So far I've defined my function using a ClassManifest like so:

```
def get[R: ClassManifest](representation: R): String = {
  val jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(classManifest[R].erasure)
  ...
}
```

My first question is a bit of a silly one: how do I call this function? I can't figure out what to pass in to get() for the R type and the representation value (the accepted answer to the original question doesn't make this clear). I tried implicit typing as per paradigmatic's comment but the below generates a compile error:

```
get(PlatformRepresentation)

Compiling main sources... 
  not found: value PlatformRepresentation
```

My second question is: is it possible to apply an upper type bound on the R object? In other words, I know that:

```
R <: Representation
```

Is there a way of bounding this in get()'s ClassManifest type declaration?

Many thanks!

Comment: To call it, just pass an argument to `get` the type will be inferred.

Comment: Thanks paradigmatic - I have updated my question. I'm trying to clarify that I don't have a value to pass in to the get(), I only have a class name to pass in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to suppress the argument if you don't have any:

```
def get[R <: Representation: ClassManifest]: String = {
    val classManifest = implicitly[ClassManifest[R]] //to retrieve the class manifest
}
```

To call it:

```
get[PlatformRepresentation]
```

The type gets between square brackets.

Comment: Big thanks paradigmatic, that worked great. I found a great explanation of implicit parameters here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855595/scala-function-implicitly

Answer (score 3):

About your second question: yes, there is a way to do that:

```
def get[R <: Representation: ClassManifest](representation: R): String
```

When you declare type parameters, you may include one lower bound with `>:`, one upper bound with `<:`, and as many context bounds (with `:`) and view bounds (with `<%`) that you need.

Answer (score 1):

an example:

```
scala> def b[T <: String : ClassManifest] (t:T) = t + " " + classManifest[T].era
sure;
b: [T <: String](t: T)(implicit evidence$1: ClassManifest[T])java.lang.String

scala> b("hello")
res2: java.lang.String = hello class java.lang.String
```

**EDIT** @paradigmatic is right, in your case it should be

```
scala> def c[T <: String : ClassManifest] = classManifest[T].erasure;
c: [T <: String](implicit evidence$1: ClassManifest[T])java.lang.Class[_]

scala> c[String];
res4: java.lang.Class[_] = class java.lang.String
```

Comment: Thanks paolo - but I don't have a value to pass in to b, I just have the class name. In other words, I need b(String) to work not b("string") (which of course it doesn't).