# using scala generics in function definition

Tags: scala

I'd like to build a convinient function for making akka actors:

```
 def makeActor[T](id: Int): ActorRef =
   system.actorOf(Props(classOf[T], id, updater), "entity" + id)

 makeActor[SomeActor](1) ! "Some Message"
```

But this says "class type required but T found". Whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer can be found here: [Scala classOf for type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200253/scala-classof-for-type-parameter)

You can write your code for example like this:

```
def makeActor[T](id: Int)(implicit ev: Manifest[T]): ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(ev.erasure, id, updater), "entity" + id)
```

Comment: I used `ev.runtimeClass` because `ev.erasure` is deprecated in 2.10. I've edited your post. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

Use scala reflection for this, e.g:

```
import scala.reflect._

def spawn[T <: Actor: ClassTag](id: Int) = system.actorOf(Props(classTag[T].runtimeClass, ...), s"entity$id")
```

Comment: I think you meant `def spawn[T: ClassTag]`. I can't propose an edit because it's too small.

Answer (score 2):

Fully working example:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props, Actor, ActorRef}
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object TestActor extends App {

  val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("rest-service-actor-system")

  def makeActor[T <: Actor : ClassTag](id: Int): ActorRef =
    system.actorOf(Props(implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass), "entity" + id)

  class A extends Actor {
    override def receive = {
      case anything => println("A GOT MESSAGE: " + anything)
    }
  }

  class B extends Actor {
    override def receive = {
      case anything => println("B GOT MESSAGE: " + anything)
    }
  }

  makeActor[A](1) ! "hello"
  makeActor[A](2) ! "bye"

  system.shutdown()
}
```

usually prints:

```
A GOT MESSAGE: bye
A GOT MESSAGE: hello
```

It forces you to have a type that is also an `Actor`. For instance this code will not compile:

```
class C

makeActor[C](3)
```

error you get is:

```
type arguments [TestActor.C] do not conform to method makeActor's type parameter bounds [T <: akka.actor.Actor]
  makeActor[C](3)
           ^
```